# Can Firebug show font-size inheritance tree when using em?

Tags: css, firebug, firefox-addon

Sometimes some text shows larger than what I expect because the font size in em is based on its parent and the parent on its parent.

I would like to see as a visual cue in Firebug or Web developer instead of going up the tree manually to figure out which parent was the cause of the an expected font size.
What I am saying I know what is happening. I just need a tool to view this fact at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

This has bothered me on multiple occasions.  Unfortunately, firebug does not currently provide the information you are looking for.  There is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1011&q=font-size&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Test%20Summary) about this issue but it doesn't appear to have had much activity recentyl.

Answer (score 1):

In the style pane for the element, just scroll down till you see the inherited `font-size` attribute from the parents. It show all inherited attributes, with a strike-through for overridden ones.

Comment: strike-through usually means not used and overridden by child. Looking for something like the hierarchy tree in one line. parent -> parent -> parent